# R: Add paste() elements to file

Tags: r, file-io, paste, write.table

I'm using `base::paste` in a for loop:

```
for (k in 1:length(summary$pro))
{
  if (k == 1)
    mp <- summary$pro[k]
  else
    mp <- paste(mp, summary$pro[k], sep = ",")
}
```

`mp` comes out as one big string, where the elements are separated by commas.

For example `mp` is `"1,2,3,4,5,6"`

Then, I want to put `mp` in a file, where each of its elements is added to a separate column in the same row. My code for this is:

```
write.table(mp, file = recompdatafile, sep = ",")
```

However, `mp` just appears in the CSV as one big string as opposed to being divided up. How can I achieve my desired format?

FYI
I've also tried converting `mp` to a list, and `strsplit()`-ing it, neither of which have worked.

Once I've added `summary$pro` to the file, how can I also add `summary$me` (which has the same format), in one row with multiple columns?

Thanks,

n.i.

Comment: Your original code would be much more succinct as `paste(summary$pro, collapse = ",")`.  With that said why do you convert to mp before writing to the table when just using summary$pro directly would be much easier...

Comment: Every iteration of the for loop adds an element to `mp`. Also `summary$pro` has headers that I don't want.

Comment: @newintern I would suggest reading some intro R material.  It seems you aren't used to thinking in terms of vectors yet and making that jump will really help you with R.

Comment: Quick follow up question though - I'm able to use the code above to add `summary$pro` to my CSV. When I use the following code (`cat(paste(summary$me, collapse=","), file=recompdatafile, append = TRUE)`) to add `summary$me` to the same CSV, the last element of `summary$pro` is combined with the first element of `summary$me`. Is there a way I can correct this? Thanks, n.i.

Comment: I would avoid using cat for that purpose.  Try switching back to write.table and see if you have the same issue.

Comment: I just tried that, but I get the unwanted headers in the file.

Comment: And why do you say that you would avoid `cat()`, just out of curiosity? Thanks, n.i.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write something to a file, `write.table()` isn't the only way. If you want to avoid headers and quotes and such, you can use the more direct `cat`. For example

```
cat(summary$pro, sep=",", file="filename.txt")
```

will write out the vector of values from `summary$pro` separated by commas more directly. You don't need to build a string first. (And building a string one element at a time as you did above is a bad practice anyway. Most functions in R can operate on an entire vector at a time, including `paste`).

Comment: Quick follow up question: I'm able to add `summary$pro` to the file, but now I want to add `summary$me`. For this I'm using: `cat(paste(summary$me, collapse=","), file=recompdatafile, append = TRUE)`. However, this combines the last element of `summary$pro` and the first element of `summary$me`. Is there a way I can correct this? Thanks for your help, n.i.

Comment: Just add an explicit new line ("\n") to the file with `cat`. Read the `?cat` help page for more info.

Comment: But if you really are creating tabular data, than write.table may be the better choice. There are options for disabling quotes and headers. How many such lines are you going to write?

Comment: Thanks for the response. However, I want `summary$me` adjacent to `summary$pro`. That is, both should be in the same row, separate columns.

Comment: I'll be writing about 500 lines.

Comment: Then just do `cat(summary$pro, summary$me, sep=",", file="filename.txt")` or if you have to call it separately, the second time use `cat(character(0), summary$me, sep=",", file="filename.txt", append=T)`

Comment: I tried that already. That pairs each element of `summary$pro` with `summary$me`.

Comment: Are you sure you tried exactly that? For me it writes out as one long line. This really should have been included in your original question. It's not good form to open new issues in the comments.

Comment: Your first second solution works. Thanks - I'll update my question to include this issue as well. n.i.